# delete table row using laravel 5.3 and jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, modal-dialog, laravel-5.3

I have users table and each row contain a button to delete user row.
 the clic on the button display a modal for delete confirmation .
but I still have this error when a try to delete the row.
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException

this is the Modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade " id="modal-delete">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Voulez-vous supprimer cet utilisateur ?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
    <!------------------------
          <a href='/SurveyApp/public/admin/{{ $user->id }}/delete' class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" class=" modal-action waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text">oui</a>
    ---------------->
  <form method="POST" action="/SurveyApp/public/admin/{{ $user->id }}/delete" id="delete-court-form">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                      data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
           <!--  <a href='/SurveyApp/public/admin/{{ $user->id }}/delete' class="btn btn-danger">oui!</a> -->
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-court-button" >
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Oui
              </button>

            </form>
```

My jquery code:

```
<script>
$('.delete-court-button').on('click', function () {
    $('#delete-court-form').attr('action', $(this).data('delete-link'));
});
</script>
```

and the method in the controller:

```
public function delete(User $user){
    $user = User::findOrFail($user->id);  
    $surveys=Survey::where('user_id',$user->id)->get(); 
        $user->delete();
    foreach($surveys as $survey){
    $survey->delete();
    }

    return redirect('/admin/user');
    }

Route::get('/admin/{user}/delete','AdminController@delete')->name('delete.user')->middleware('is_admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You use DELETE method to send your form but in your route definition you use GET. They should be the same.
2. Use `route()` helper to create your delete link

So your form should look like this:

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('delete.user',$user->id)}}" id="delete-court-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            data-dismiss="modal">Fermer
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-court-button">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Oui
        </button>
    </form>
```

And your route definition:

```
Route::delete('/admin/{user}/delete','AdminController@delete')->name('delete.user')->middleware('is_admin');
```

And your controller method:

```
public function delete($user_id){
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);  
    $surveys=Survey::where('user_id',$user->id)->get(); 
        $user->delete();
    foreach($surveys as $survey){
    $survey->delete();
    }

    return redirect('/admin/user');
    }
```

Comment: thank you , delete  action works now but it always delete the last row in the table even if I choose another one.

Comment: @Sara I've updated my aswer. Try to change your delete method as i did.

Comment: @ Andriy Lozynskiy same problem here

Comment: @Sara I think it's because your script that changes action attribute in your form doesn't work. I don't see any elements with 'data-delete-link' attribute in your question.

Answer (score 0):

check your route

example :
 Route:post('/admin/{user}/delete','AdminController@delete')

both form and route methods are should have a same method("POST")